# How to apply style on NoOptionsText in autocomplete material-ui

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, styles

i want to change color of no options. can you please help me

[image: image link]

```
<Autocomplete
  id="id"
  options={options}
  limitTags={3}
  value={value}
  noOptionsText="no options"
  getOptionLabel={option => option}
  onChange={onChange}
  renderInput={params => (
   <TextField
   {...params}
   label=" title"
   placeholder="Please select"
   />
 )}
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `classes` props to apply styles to a specific sub-component of the `Autocomplete` component

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  noOptions: {
    color: "red",
    backgroundColor: "pink"
  }
});

export default function Demo() {
  const styles = useStyles();
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      classes={{
        noOptions: styles.noOptions
      }}
      options={top100Films}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 63949999/how-to-apply-style-on-nooptionstext-in-autocomplete-material-ui/63950742#63950742]

Answer (score 3):

In mui v5 there are different approaches

**Solution 1**
To use themeProvider

```
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    // Name of the component
    MuiAutocomplete: {
      styleOverrides: {
        // Name of the slot
        noOptions: {
          // Some CSS
          color: "red",
          backgroundColor: "pink",
        },
      },
    },
  },
});


<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
<Autocomplete
  id="id"
  options={options}
  limitTags={3}
  value={value}
  noOptionsText="no options"
  getOptionLabel={option => option}
  onChange={onChange}
  renderInput={params => (
   <TextField
   {...params}
   label=" title"
   placeholder="Please select"
   />
 )}
/>
</ThemeProvider>
```

**Solution 2**
To use css class for noOption prop which is `.MuiAutocomplete-noOptions`

css file:

```
.MuiAutocomplete-noOptions {
    background-color: pink;
    color: red!important;
}
```